# how to write or read from XML config file (.config)

Tags: xml, config, nsis

I have to write a config file in the post section of installation and read from the config file if older version of the product exists.

config file is XML Configuration File (.config)
config file will have so many entries like

```
<name>
   abcd
</name>
<company>
    xyz
</company>
<choise>
   choise1
</choise>
```

How to read only choise tag's text and overwrite only choise tag's text.

Comment: Above entries of config file had some formatting problem so please find the below comment for it -
<name>abcd</name>
<company>xyz</company>
<choise>choise1</choise>

Answer (score 2):

NSIS has a total of 4 XML plug-ins to choose from; [NsisXML (by Wizou)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisXML_plug-in_%28by_Wizou%29), [XML plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/XML_plug-in), [NsisXML (by Joel)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisXML_plug-in_%28by_Joel%29) and [NsXML](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsXML_plug-in_%28by_rsegal%29)

Using NsisXML (by Wizou):

```
Outfile "$%temp%\NSISTest.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel user
Installdir "$Temp"
Showinstdetails show
!include LogicLib.nsh
Page InstFiles

!define XMLFILE "$instdir\myxml.xml"

Section
StrCpy $9 "Did not exist"
nsisXML::create
nsisXML::load "${XMLFILE}"
${If} $0 = 0
    ;build a new basic XML file:
    nsisXML::create
    nsisXML::createProcessingInstruction "xml" 'version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"'
    nsisXML::appendChild
    nsisXML::release $2
${EndIf}
nsisXML::select '/choise'
${If} $2 = 0
    StrCpy $1 $0
    nsisXML::createElement "choise"
    nsisXML::appendChild
${Else}
    nsisXML::getText
    StrCpy $9 $3
${EndIf}
DetailPrint "Old value: $9"
System::Call 'kernel32::GetTickCount()i.r5' ;Get some "random" value to save
nsisXML::setText "$5"
nsisXML::release $2
nsisXML::save "${XMLFILE}"
nsisXML::release $0
DetailPrint "Saved new value: $5"
SectionEnd
```

On first run I get:

```
Old value: Did not exist
Saved new value: 709289703
Completed
```

and on the second run I got:

```
Old value: 709289703
Saved new value: 709308687
Completed
```

Comment: which plugin is the most recommended one ?

Comment: @lysergic-acid: You should use the one that best fits your needs (I don't use any of them so I can't really tell you which is best)