# how to read particular element from xml in nsis without using plugins

Tags: xml, installation, nsis

In my windows NSIS installer, I need to read few values from xml (config) file. 
Can any1 please let me know how to read values from xml without using plugins?

thanks,

Comment: Why can't you use the existing XML plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the answer I gave you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755393/how-to-write-or-read-from-xml-config-file-config)?

The pluginless requirement is pretty dumb IMHO but if you really really wanted to do it you could create a basic XML reader by just using FileOpen, FileRead, StrCpy and StrLen (The basic building blocks of any pluginless text based file reader). This will require a lot of work and you are probably not going to be able to follow all XML parsing rules, and without any kind of XPath/query support or nodes in general you will have put your data extraction logic inside your little XML parser!

Comment: all these(xml,ipconfig and windows service) plugins are not included in official nsis version 2.46, So i think if i use any1 of these plugins in my company proprietary code, my company may run into legal issues. what do u suggest on this Anders?

Comment: @sr164w: Some plugins have a specific license, if not then the NSIS Wiki default license applies: "All contributions sent to this wiki are generally considered to be in the zlib/libpng license". The plugin I used in the other answer is zlib, see the bottom @ http://wiz0u.free.fr/prog/nsisXML/

Comment: ...and AFAIK, all (public) NSIS plugins are either open source or freeware and they all allow binary distribution in commercial installers. (IANAL)

Comment: I am very sorry if i ask very basic questions. in my local nsis installed directory i can put those plugins and compile my code but when i check in my code and plugin dlls will not be there in my build machine nsis. In this case what should i do?  Should i checking these plugins dlls also with my code?

Comment: @sr164w: That is up to you, I cannot tell you how to organize your build system...

Comment: Could u please give me some ideas to achieve above using MSXML instead of plugins. this would be great help from, thanks in advance.

Comment: @sr164w: There are already like 5 XML plugins and I'm sure some of them use MSXML under the hood, check their documentation...